# Reading PDF text as hierarchical data

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I am trying to read a PDF file with in c#, the format of this typical PDF is contents with pages heading, sub headings and content and so on so forth. The data is more as hierarchical and not flat.

I actually want to read data hierarchical and have it as shown below:

[image]

I tried iText Sharp and I could only read each page as normal text and the text contains header, footer, page numbers etc, which is redundant for me.

Is there a way I can read the PDF page as hierarchical page/content?

Comment: Difficult to say since you haven't provided code or sample input.

Comment: Is your PDF a Tagged PDF? If not, your PDF isn't aware of any hierarchy in its content. If it's a properly Tagged PDF, you can easily extract the content as an XML file. Note that I assume that you're using an old version of iText, since you still talk about "iTextSharp". That name was replaced by "iText for .NET" when we moved to iText7 more than two years ago.

Comment: Does it make sense to have page 2 as a sub-item of page 1?

Comment: @mkl yes, it makes sense as i mentioned in my question and image, data will be represented in hierarchical format.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks for the insight, the PDF may or may not be tagged, but leaves me with one more option to explore and possibly lead me to a solution. 

Yes you are correct, though I am using iText 7/5 in my project with VS2017 NuGet, I am not sure why i said iTextSharp, may be my brain is still old school :). btw, is iText5/7 open source? do you know if reading a PDF can be achieved using open source tool(s)?

Comment: iText is Open Source. The license is AGPL. This means, if you distribute your software, it must also be AGPL, in other words your end users must also have access to your source code. If you are unable to give your source code to your end users (for example your software is commercial) then you can purchase a license from iText Software that releases you from the AGPL requirements.

Answer (score 1):

No. The closest you'll get is 'pdf to html' then you can read through the html tags.

You want the text AND the layout. Prepare for a lot of parsing and 'why did they do it like that??' moments :)

For most things, I can use the raw text. It'll likely be split up by LF rather than CRLF, but that's fine.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Can i convert pdf to html using iText5 or iText7? or should I use any other software(s)? I am checking now anyways.

Comment: Is your file properly tagged? That determines the answer to your question.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot make sure if the target PDF is tagged or not.

Comment: Don't worry, I don't know what he means by 'tagged' either, and I've been wrangling computers for a long time. Just pdf2html with some kinda library, then parse through the html. It'll be a mess and effort, but it'll work :)